# How does the word2vec produce embeddings for the unseen words?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm using an **unlabeled** news corpus to fine-tune the Word2Vec model. After that I'm using those embeddings to generate embeddings for words present in a new **labeled** dataset. These new embeddings were fed to an RNN as initial weights. I've shared the code for generating the embedding matrix:

```
embed_dim = embedding_size
words_not_found = []
nb_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index))
embedding_matrix = np.random.rand(nb_words+1, embed_dim)

    for word, i in word_index.items():
        if i >= nb_words:
            continue
        #print(word)
    
        if embeddings_index.wv.__contains__(word): 
    
            embedding_vector = embeddings_index.wv[word]
        
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
        else:
            words_not_found.append(word)
```

I've seen that the matrix contains embeddings for all of the unique words in the new **labeled** dataset.

**Can anyone tell me how did the word2vec model produce embeddings for the words which were not present in the initial news corpus?**

Answer (score 0):

Standard word2vec models don't offer word-vectors for words that weren't in their training data. (FastText can do this, by synthesizing a guess-vector using word-fragments that it learned suggestive word-vectors for.)

Whether your datasets are labeled or not is irrelevant with respect to word2vec processes, which are an 'unsupervised' technique. That is, they're not trying to match your labels of desired results, they're just working off patterns in the training data.

It's unclear what you mean by 'fine-tuning' here, as that could describe lots of possible processes, and you've not shown the code you used, or even the word2vec/training libraries you might be using.

It looks (from the `.wv` access) that it might be Gensim. If so, the only reason your `embeddings_index` object (whose origin isn't shown in your code) would have a value for a word would be if earlier intialization steps were provided texts that include that word. That is, in some way (unshown) you gave the model your new corpus (the one you calll 'labeled') and asked it to add those words.